# Cannot send private message to all authenticated users by rules

Tags: rules, privatemsg

I am trying to broadcast a private message ([privatemsg](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg)) to all authenticated users when adding a new node of specific content type.

However, I cannot find **Authenticated user** option on the roles select box (these're only user-defined ones, no system roles).

I tried to use a specific user to send the message (the permission to send to a role is granted), and set the role parameter to `[selected-user:roles]` to send to same roles as the user himself. However, the authenticated users still could not receive the message, and users of other roles (like member, administrator) could receive it.

The message could be successfully sent to all authenticated users via `/messages/new` form.

What is the problem?

### I found the answer

It turns out that the users could receive the messages **after the cron is run**.